# Can a stunned (Stupefied) wizard hear the surroundings?

Tags: harry-potter

If a wizard is stunned using the stupefy spell, can he hear other wizards conversing near him. Does the communication falling in his ear enters his mind with all recollections?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. The [stupefying charm](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Stunning_Spell) renders the victim ***unconscious*** for a period of time. It follows that they wouldn't be able to hear anything while they were in this state, although it's possible that they would be able to hear their surroundings in the brief period as they were *regaining* consciousness.

> Then he returned to the Gaunt hovel, performed the complex bit of magic that would implant a false memory in his uncle’s mind, **laid Morfin’s wand beside its unconscious owner,** pocketed the ancient ring he wore and departed.’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>

and

> **Stupefy:** *Stunning is one of the most useful spells in the wizard’s arsenal. It renders the victim unconscious.*
>
> *The effects of the Stunning Spell may be counteracted by ‘Rennervate’, but will also wear off with time on their own.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The most important spells Harry taught Dumbledore’s Army](https://www.wizardingworld.com/features/the-most-important-spells-harry-taught-da)</sup></sub>